# Which refactoring tools can rename a Java class along with all its similarly-named instances?

Tags: java, netbeans, refactoring, rename, automated-refactoring

Suppose I have a class called `Orange` in my NetBeans Java project, which I'd like to rename to `Apple`. The NetBeans rename refactoring can handle this without difficulty. However, my project contains many instances of the `Orange` class with the name `orange`, resulting in a lot of confusing refactored code along the lines of:

```
final Apple orange = new Apple();
```

I'd like all these instances -- and preferably also prefixed ones like `juicyOrange` and `defaultOrange` -- to be renamed to `apple`, `juicyApple`, etc. as part of the same refactoring. The refactoring should of course not affect variables of different classes (e.g. `Colour orange` should remain as-is), or `orange` occurrences where there's already an `apple` variable in context. It seems that [IntelliJ IDEA](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/rename-refactorings.html) offers this functionality, but I can't find it in NetBeans 8.2.

Is this functionality available or planned either in NetBeans itself or in any NetBeans plug-in? Failing that, is there any stand-alone Java refactoring tool which offers it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It seems that IntelliJ IDEA offers this functionality, but I can't
>   find it in NetBeans 8.2.

The refactoring functionality you describe in Intellij IDEA does not exist in NetBeans 8.2, nor in NetBeans 9.0.

> Is this functionality available or planned either in NetBeans itself
>   or in any NetBeans plug-in?

I don't know of any plans to add this functionality, nor do I know of any NetBeans plugin that does what you want. If you would like this functionality to be added to Apache NetBeans 9.0 [consider raising an enhancement request through a bug report](https://issues.apache.org/jira/projects/NETBEANS/issues/NETBEANS-1321?filter=allopenissues).

That said, the functionality provided by **Edit > Replace in Projects...** might be worth looking at as a cruder alternative:

[image: ReplaceInProjects]

- You can provide a regular expression for the text to search for.
- The files to be considered for modification can be specified in several ways:

  - The current project.
  - Selected projects.
  - All open projects.
  - Open files.
  - Selected files.
- You can additionally provide a pattern for the files to be modified, allowing for complex selection. For example:

  - Modify all files containing *"Widget"* in their name with file extension *"jsf"* in projects *A*, *B* and *C*.
  - Modify only open files with the extension *"properties"*.

Of course this functionality is not sophisticated, and it will blindly do whatever you tell it. It cannot handle the `Colour orange` scenario you described (unless you ensure that the relevant files are excluded based on your file selection criteria).

> Failing that, is there any stand-alone Java refactoring tool which
>   offers it?

Recommending software is specifically off topic here, though that has been asked in some closed questions here. (See [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic))

Comment: Thank you for the thorough answer and suggested workaround. I suspected that the answer was "no" but wanted to be sure. I'll file a feature request for the NetBeans functionality and try my off-topic question at softwarerecs.se.